# "The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read is not valid" error while getting access token for my app

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use MS graph API to access user's calendar events but while trying to get the access token for my app that I registered in azure,

I am getting the following error:

> Error : The scope https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read is not
>   valid.

Below is my code:

```
string token = string.Empty;
            IConfidentialClientApplication app;
            app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create("ClientID")
                .WithTenantId("TenantID")
                .WithClientSecret("ClientSecret")
                .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.Read" };

            AuthenticationResult result = null;

            try
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
                token = result.AccessToken;

                var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
                    requestMessage
                        .Headers
                        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));

                var events = await graphServiceClient.Users["user1@onTestMicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().GetAsync();


            }
            catch (MsalServiceException ex)
            {
                // Case when ex.Message contains:
                // AADSTS70011 Invalid scope. The scope has to be of the form "https://resourceUrl/.default"
                // Mitigation: change the scope to be as expected
            }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have already granted permission to Calendars.Read in azure portal while registering my app there: https://www.screencast.com/t/jTjnB4SX5I

Comment: Interesting. Try making the scope just `Calendars.Read`.

Comment: I tried that too but same result. Started giving ```The scope Calendars.Read is not valid.```

Comment: Ah, missed that you're doing client credential flow. In that case, try using just the scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`.

Comment: I actually had tried that and got the access token :) but when I use that token to read the calendar events for a user I get this error: ```"Code: NoPermissionsInAccessToken, Message: The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood."```

Comment: My code where I am trying to get the events: ```var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) => {
                    requestMessage
                        .Headers
                        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }));

                var events = await graphServiceClient.Users["user1@onTestMicrosoft.com"].Events.Request().GetAsync();```

Comment: and this is how my app's permissions look like: https://www.screencast.com/t/jTjnB4SX5I

Comment: Gotcha. I'll post an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here.

1. When you use the client credentials flow, you're required to use a scope of the form `{resource}/.default`, where `{resource}` is the URL of the thing you want access to. In this case, your scope should be `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token))
2. You have not configured any application permissions on your app registration. From your screenshot, you've only configured delegated permissions, which are user permissions that require a logged in user. Add `Calendars.Read` as an application permission and that should get you going.

Comment: Thanks Jason, how do I add it as an application permission? I am not seeing an option in the azure portal. Might be missing something here. However in Enterprise Applications > Permission I am seeing this: https://www.screencast.com/t/STU1c8jX Thanks.

Comment: was able to figure that out. Cheers.